# If $e^{f(z)}$ is analytic then $f(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know how to prove that if $e^{f(z)}$ is analytic in some open disk then $f(z)$ is analytic in that open disk. Can someone guide me through this? thanks!

Comment: Hint: Any continuous branch of the logarithm function is analytic.

Comment: You need some restrictions on $f$. Otherwise take $f(z) = 0$ if $z$ has rational coordinates and $f(z) = 2 \pi i$ otherwise; then $f$ is not analytic but $e^f \equiv 1$ is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi what if we say $e^{f(z)}$ is non constant?

Answer (score -1):

Let $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$ where $g$ is analytic. Therefore, $$g'(z)=f'(z)e^{f(z)}\implies f'(z)=\frac{g'(z)}{e^{f(z)}}$$ is analytic (because quotient of two analytic function and $e^{f(z)}\neq 0$ for all $z$). Therefore $f'$ is analytic and thus $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Can you apply the chain rule when you haven't proved that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: @ajotatxe interesting point. If f' is analytic how can you say f is analytic? I know the converse is true

Comment: It's true that when $f'$ is analytic, then $f$ is analytic, but the problem is: Does $f'$ even exist?

Comment: @ajotatxe How can you say hat?

Comment: @ajotatxe since $e^f$ is analytic f' should exist right? because the derivative too is analytic